# No abrir teclado al iniciar app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo un problema muy simple pero no se como solucionarlo. Tengo este formulario en android studio.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/flexpointlogo_blanco"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/usuario"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/Usuario"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/clave"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="6"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Ingresar"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Forgot_Password"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Al iniciar mi app entra al Primer `EditText` y abre el teclado, es muy molesto existe alguna forma de que no pase esto o quitarle el focus a ese elemento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu `Manifest.xml` puedes definir que el teclado no se lance al iniciar la actividad, aquí un ejemplo:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
       />
```

Comment: Gracias por ayudar :,)

Comment: omite el landscape, esa actividad solo se muestra en modo horizontal

Comment: Si, solo tome la segunda linea de verdad muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Esto se puede realizar de varias formas, el teclado se abre porque al iniciar una `EditText` toma el enfoque y muestra automáticamente el teclado virtual.

Puedes evitar se abra el teclado usando [setSoftInputMode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setSoftInputMode(int)) y la constante [SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN) que indica ocultar cualquier área de entrada cuando el usuario navega hacia su ventana, en este caso el EditText.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

---

otra opción es definir la misma propiedad en tu `Activity`:

```
<activity
        ... 
        ...
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
        ...
        ...
        >
```

---

también puedes asignar al Layout contenedor :

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

por ejemplo:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
```